# Hibernate + Dropwizard, MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown database 'test_db;'

Tags: java, hibernate, dropwizard

I have a simple dropwizard application, and I have written the following yml for the configuration.

```
template: Hello, %s!
defaultName: Stranger
database:
  driverClass: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
  user: rootUser
  password: rootPassword
  url: jdbc:mysql://<SQL SERVER IP>:<SQL SERVER IP>/test_db;
  properties:
    charSet: UTF-8
    hibernate.dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
```

and here is how I add it in my application's "run" method :

```
    // Setting up the database.
    final DBIFactory factory = new DBIFactory();
    final DBI jdbi = factory.build(environment, configuration.getDataSourceFactory(), "mysql");

    //Hibernate
    final UserDAO dao = new UserDAO(hibernate.getSessionFactory());
    environment.jersey().register(new UserResource(dao));
```

Also, in that same class, I have the following method, which brings into play, the hibernate bundle :

```
private final HibernateBundle<ServerConfiguration> hibernate = new HibernateBundle<ServerConfiguration>(User.class) {
    @Override
    public DataSourceFactory getDataSourceFactory(ServerConfiguration configuration) {
        return configuration.getDataSourceFactory();
    }
};
```

Now, this all builds, but when I try to run the jar and also use the yml file with it... I get the following error :

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown database 'test_db;'
```

I know the db is there, at that location, because I cam use dBeaver to add records to the tbl_users table.

any ideas, anyone?

Comment: Are you certain the server IP and PORT are correct on your JDBC url?

Comment: Yeah, 100% - I am able to connect to it with those details in a SQL client.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the trailing `;` from your database.url property and it will work.  The trailing `;` is being included as part of the database name wihch is causing the failure.